# Ajax sending empty array to php file

Tags: php, ajax, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to get the Google API working and I'm sending an array via AJAX to PHP but in my PHP file the array is empty. Here is what I got so far.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../scripts/email/google.php?storeToken&state',
    data: {param : param},
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    processData: false
});
```

Then inside my google.php file I'm using

```
$code = explode(",",file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

But $code is empty, also when I use

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

it prints to the console

```
Array(0){
}
```

I've googled the problem and tried countless "fixes" but nothing seems to be working :/

Edit: is there another way I can get the Code and my state variables in the php file other than using AJAX, as nothing seems to work

```
Error_log (print_r ($_POST,1));
```

the expected values are printed to the error log

Comment: Why do you have `processData: false`?

Comment: what is the value of `param`

Comment: @Musa I followed a tutorial I found on stackoverflow and thats what was on there I did test setting it to true earlier today but it didn't change anything I shall try again now with the new changes I've made.

Edit: still empty after the change from false to true

Comment: @Victory the values of param are 

    var param = new Array();
    var param = [authResult['code'],state];

Comment: Check the value of param by putting console.log(param) before calling the ajax. What do you get ? and also try setting the option processData: true and test it !

Comment: @RahulGupta when using console.log(param) before the ajax call it prints out the expected values, I have also changed processData to true and still empty values on the php side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this by changing my code to the following

```
var params = 
{ 
'authResult': authResult['code'],
'state':state
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../scripts/email/google.php?storeToken&state/',
    data: params
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    processData: true
  });
```

Then in the php file accessed it in the following way

```
$authResult = $_POST['authResult'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JSON.stringify` function like:

```
$.ajax({ 
     type: 'POST',
     url: '../scripts/emailgoogle.php?storeToken&state',                                          
     data       : {'mydata':JSON.stringify(param)},
     success: function(result) {
         console.log(result);
     }
   });
```

On server side `PHP` file:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($data, true);
var_dump($data);

$post_data = $_POST;
var_dump($post_data);
```

Comment: Changed it to {mydata:param}, and still the array is empty

Comment: Tried the new changes and it outputs the following to the html "NULL
array(0) {
}" and gives the following error in the console 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token N jquery.min.js:4
m.parseJSON jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function) dashboard:597
j jquery.min.js:2
k.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
x jquery.min.js:4
b